# google cloud functions から google drive にアクセスしたい

Tags: python, google-drive-sdk

google cloud functions から google drive にアクセスし、ファイルのダウンロード・アップロードを行いたいと考えています。

以下の Drive APIのドキュメントを参照してアクセスを試みているのですが、うまくいきません。

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python?authuser=1

具体的には、

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
       'credentials.json', SCOPES)
```

のところで、「[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'」
というエラーが出ます。

対処法についてご存知の方いらっしゃったら、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

あるいは、上記URL以外のやり方をご存知であればご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: 参照されたサイトのCreate Credentialsのリンク先の手順にそってcredentials.jsonファイルがちゃんと作成されていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
credentials.jsonファイルを作成し、フォルダに配置したところ成功しました。

Comment: お時間のある時で構いませんので、ご自身で解決された内容を回答にまとめて自己解決ということで質問を閉じてください。そうすると後で同じような疑問をもった人がこのページを見つけた時に解決につながりやすくなります。